# How to handle async getJSON to copy json objects?

Tags: javascript, json

How to assign/clone received `JSON` object to previously defines JavaScript Object `booksJSON` ? I need to make `booksJSON` accessible and visible for all functions.

```
var booksJSON = {};
    function getBooks(){
    $.getJSON( "bookstore.json", function( json ) {

        $.each(json.books, function(i, json){
            renderEntity(json);
        });
        booksJSON  =  json;  // CLONE OBJECTS 
   });
}
```

UPDATE:

New code:

```
    var booksJSON = {};
function getBooks(){
    return $.getJSON( "bookstore.json" );
}


$(document).ready(function(){

     getBooks();
     getBooks().done(function(json) {
        $.each(json.books, function(i, json){
            renderEntity(json);
        });
        booksJSON = json;
        alert(JSON.stringify(booksJSON));
    });

});
```

Comment: why you want to clone? I mean why just assign it into the bookJSON variable?

Comment: I need to be able to store JSON Object and use outside of 'getBooks()'

Comment: You can't, the data has'nt downloaded yet, and it's not there for you to use !

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196.

Comment: @FelixKling - I was actually looking for that answer, but could'nt find it!

Comment: @adeneo: Mmh, maybe the title of the question is not "good" enough? I hoped it was easily searchable :-/

Comment: @FelixKling - Now I know where it is, I've seen it before. Was searching for "async problems" etc. here on SO, and only got crap questions as results ?

Comment: you have to wait for the onsuccess event I see somebody already resolve the question... best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with cloning! `$.getJSON` is **asynchronous** and you can't use the data before it's available once the `$.getJSON` function has completed, and that's what the success callback is there for.

```
var booksJSON = {};
function getBooks(){
    $.getJSON( "bookstore.json", function( json ) {

        /* This is an async function, it executes at a later time */

        $.each(json.books, function(i, json){
            renderEntity(json);
        });
        booksJSON  =  json;  // here json is available
   });
   console.log( booksJSON ); // this happens before the above function, 
                             // so here booksJSON is still an empty object, 
                             // as nothing has been added yet
}
```

The only thing you can do is something like :

```
function getBooks(){
    return $.getJSON( "bookstore.json" );
}

getBooks().done(function(json) {
    $.each(json.books, function(i, json){
        renderEntity(json);
    });
});
```

If that helps any ?

Comment: I think `function( json ){...}` is executed after json received because I have valid json object passed to `renderEntity(json);`. Then why if I use `booksJSON  = json;` it returns empty object?

Comment: getBooks().done nice!! didnt know you can do that...